# How to load localized asset variants in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, localization

Flutter documentation talks about [asset variants](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-variants) for loading image assets. Variants are for resolution and themes.

I have a similar scenario, but instead of images I need to load some `JSON data` that is `language/locale specific`. How can I specify asset variants for different locales and for non-image files?

I am currently using `localized` strings to store `JSON` file names and am loading using below code.

```
 var t = AppLocalizations.of(context);
 await rootBundle.load(t!.localizedJsonPath);
```

But this means I have to deploy `JSON` files for all supported `languages` to user's device. I would like for Flutter to only deploy the file required by the user based on her `locale`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with help of `path_provider` package, [link](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

for that you have to do following steps,

1. download json from server or backend when user select different language and save it in `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` using path_provider.
2. now you have json file in users device then all you have to do is provide that path to your locale.

```
 var t = AppLocalizations.of(context);
 await rootBundle.load(t!.localizedJsonPath);   <-- new path from path_provider
```

Comment: I don't want to use a server. With Microsoft, the store takes care of this. You provide assets for different locales and the installer selects the correct ones when the user installs. Can flutter and Google store not do the same? Maintaining my own back end infrastructure for a small app is too much overhead.